# Don't know how to activate Wifi in "Try" mode

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, broadcom

Mine is a `Mac mini` with a `Broadcom` `BCM4331` card. And I'm trying Mantic Minotaur (Desktop Version). How do I activate WiFi through terminal in here? It was a really simple task when I was in Jammy Jellyfish desktop version: Just make an installation process begin, and when  the "Third Party drivers" page popped up, I just click on that radio button and then click on the "Continue" button". And then I can quit the installation process. When going to the "Settings" voilà!, the WiFi function is showing up on top of the Settings list. But in Mantic version, that's not happening any more, so I don't know what I should do next. I don't want to install it (not yet), until I get some big drive for file backup. Please be gentle, I am a newbie in Ubuntu, but I am NOT a newbie in Computer usage.

Comment: You mention your release (23.10), but not which 23.10 product; is it Ubuntu 23.10 Server? Ubuntu 23.10 Desktop? etc. Some of your language makes it read you're asking about a desktop system, but it's best if you're clear & we're not guessing.

Comment: Multiple installs and an understanding of "Third Party Drivers" strongly suggests that you are not really a "newbie."

Comment: No satisfaction on these answers. Was this not supposed to be fast-helping forum? I was even disputed by #user535733!!!!

Comment: I see only mention of release (*mantic* or 23.10) not which Ubuntu product. The server systems use *netplan.io* where as desktop systems use *NetworkManager* and you've not indicated which you're using, thus we only know what release you're using; not what existed on your system (why my first comment).  By *radio* button you could mean GUI or a TUI button you select with TAB key.  (FYI: This is a Q&A site, https://ubuntuforums.org/ is the Ubuntu Forums)

Comment: Ubuntu 23.10 also has multiple installers depending on product you elect to install; eg. Ubuntu 23.10 Desktop was available with the `ubuntu-desktop-installer` or `ubiquity` installer.. Ubuntu 23.10 Server uses the `subiquity` installer (*flavors* of 23.10 use those or `calamares`); with you selecting which installer you use at download time. You haven't specified product (Server, Desktop) and thus we don't know which you attempted or are asking about. The `ubiquity` installer used by Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop is available; did you try it?